# How do I model (UML, Class Diagram) an object that is used in a method

Tags: c#, methods, uml, relationship, class-diagram

I'm working on a class diagram for an existing application (C#) and I'm struggling with the following.

Say you have two classes `A` and `B`. Class `B` contains a method `foo` that returns a list of `A` objects::

```
public class A { string V {get; set;} }

public class B { 
    string W {get; set;} 

    public List<A> foo(JObject bar) { /* do something */ }
}
```

What is the relationship that `A` has with `B` in this case when this is modelled in UML?

At first I thought this would be a one-to-many relationship where the method returns a list (one or more...) of `A`. Because when you have a list attribute in a class, it is usually a one-to-many relationship. However, I don't know if this is the same case.

In the application, the  `A` class is only used through the method `foo()`, so it would also be weird to connect it to nothing, as it would then just be a standalone class which I think is wrong too.

Comment: Your code is just confusing. You list `B` and right below you tell it has another operation which is not listed above.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit slightly your question to address the confusion that qwerty_so has noticed in the code sample. At this occasion I also renamed the string properties.I hope you agree with the revised version

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that we can say for sure is that `B` uses `A`: `B` needs to know about `A` since it returns a list thereof.

This kind of relationship is called a [dependency](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?context=class-diagrams):  more precisely, it is a [`«use»` dependency](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#usage). A dependency has no multiplicity: there is no difference if the `B` uses several times `A` or only once; the dependency just means that it has to know about `A`.

[image]

If you would have a one-to-many [association](http://%20https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) between `B` and `A`, it would mean that a structural relation: at a moment in time an instance of `B` could be [linked](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#link) with some instances of `A`s. Returning one or several A is not sufficient to create a link, because each A created and returned may be disconned from the B and as soon as the A's would be returned, B could not find them back either. No link, no association. The association would require something more durable, [comparable to a property](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#association-member-end).

Comment: You added the tag `methods` but as per UML it should be `operation`. Unfortunately the term `method` is widely used instead of `operation` (even here at SO). A `method` describes behavior. See p. 287 of UML 2.5.

Comment: @qwerty_so that's on purpose, because OP starts from C# code and asks how to model the method return type.  Here method refers to C# and not to UML.  This tag would be more useful for other people mapping some known language constructs to less known UML.

Comment: So that's actually a C# term? - Just googled for method/operation & programming. Oh well...

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods - I confess nevertheless that deep in my brain methods and operations are just another name for member functions ;-)

Comment: I had it the same way until I got deeper into UML and found a good explanation. Things are what their name is. Ontology is quite interesting....